# Decimal numbers on UGC Ratings

Tags: 2013-sp1, ugc

Can we use decimal numbers for ratings on UGC (example: 4.5), rather than integer numbers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: per my knowledge, out of the box you can only use ratings as 1 to 5

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [the API documentation](https://sdl.dist.sdlmedia.com/Distributions/?o=30263F5C-5E7B-4BE1-9A96-4C975E857019), you can get the item ratings using the following API call:

```
ItemStatsRetriever.RetrieveItemStats(PageUri)
```

This will return an `ItemStats` object.

The `AverageRating` property of this is a double. I haven't tested this, but I'd assume, therefore, that this supports decimal values.

```
public double AverageRating { get; set; }
```

---

With regards to posting ratings (i.e. a user giving an item a mark out of five), then this can only be an integer:

**WebServiceHelper.PostRating Method:**

```
public static void PostRating(
    string itemUri,
    int ratingValue
)
```

---

You can find further details about ratings in Pankaj's blog post here: https://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/2015/12/08/tridion-user-generated-content-blog-series-part-iv/